# Yaml - Can't construct a java object for !Or; exception=Invalid tag

Tags: java, parsing, groovy, yaml

I have valid Yaml file which I am trying to parse while running Jenkins pipeline but seeing error,

> init threw exception: Can't construct a java object for !Or;
>   exception=Invalid tag: !Or 15:47:45  in 'string', line 4, column 23:
>   15:47:45       CreateDevResources: !Or [!Equals [ !Ref EnvName, dev
>   ...

For reference, groovy code is something like,

```
def fileContents = readFile "appTemplate.yaml"
Yaml parser = new Yaml()
List read = parser.load(fileContents)
```

Content of Yaml file:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Conditions:
  CreateDevResources: !Or [!Equals [ !Ref EnvName, dev ],!Equals [ !Ref EnvName, dev2 ]]
Resources:
  MyAuthApi5xxErrorAlarm:
    Type: AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm
    Properties:
      ActionsEnabled : true
      AlarmActions : [ !Sub "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${EnvName}Alerter" ]
      OKActions : [ !Sub "arn:aws:sns:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:${EnvName}Alerter" ]
      AlarmDescription : 'Alerts on API Gateway GetBillingApi 5xx errors'
      AlarmName : !Sub ${AWS::StackName}Api5xxError
      ComparisonOperator : GreaterThanThreshold
      Dimensions :
        -
          Name: ApiName
          Value: !Ref "AWS::StackName"
        -
          Name: Stage
          Value: Prod
      EvaluationPeriods : 1
      MetricName : 5XXError
      Namespace : "AWS/ApiGateway"
      Period : 60
      Statistic : Average
      Threshold : 0 # start with 0 tolerance for error by default
      Unit : Count
```

Comment: please edit your question and  provide the yaml file sample that fails

Comment: `!` prefix are used to support "local data types".  But it does not know about a `Or` class.